# PhotoSwipe Navigation Does Not Respond to Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I'm using PhotoSwipe in conjunction with Jquery Masonry and navigation does not respond to input. Neither the navigation arrows or key board input (key codes 37 and 39), do not locate images forward or backwards.

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
    <div class="header-container">
        <header class="wrapper clearfix">

            <div class="menumain">
                <div id="logotype"> 
                <a href="index.html">TEST</a>
                </div>

    <nav class="menudesktop">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                </ul>                
            </div>    
    </nav>

            <a class="mtoggle"></a>
        </header>

    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="main clearfix">
        <div id="content">    



        <!-- Portfolio Rendering -->


    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer">


        <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="fashion/01.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="fashion/600/01.jpg" data-med-size="600x800" data-author="">
          <img src="fashion/600/01.jpg" alt="" class="over" /><div class="overlay"><img class="zoom" src="images/mag.png" alt="mag" width="37" height="39"></div>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="fashion/02.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="fashion/600/02.jpg" data-med-size="600x900" data-author="">
          <img src="fashion/600/02.jpg" alt="" class="over" /><div class="overlay"><img class="zoom" src="images/mag.png" alt="mag" width="37" height="39"></div>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="fashion/03.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="fashion/600/03.jpg" data-med-size="600x800" data-author="">
          <img src="fashion/600/03.jpg" alt="" class="over" /><div class="overlay"><img class="zoom" src="images/mag.png" alt="mag" width="37" height="39"></div>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="fashion/04.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="fashion/600/04.jpg" data-med-size="600x906" data-author="">
          <img src="fashion/600/04.jpg" alt="" class="over" /><div class="overlay"><img class="zoom" src="images/mag.png" alt="mag" width="37" height="39"></div>
        </a>
        </div>       


      </div>


  </div>

      </div></div></div>                        




<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

    <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

      <div class="pswp__container">
        <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        <div class="pswp__item"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

        <div class="pswp__top-bar">

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)"></button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)"></button>



            <div class="pswp__preloader">
                <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                  <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- <div class="pswp__loading-indicator"><div class="pswp__loading-indicator__line"></div></div> -->




      </div></div></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

        var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
            var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
                numNodes = thumbElements.length,
                items = [],
                el,
                childElements,
                thumbnailEl,
                size,
                item;

            for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                el = thumbElements[i];

                // include only element nodes 
                if(el.nodeType !== 1) {
                  continue;
                }

                childElements = el.children;

                size = el.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

                // create slide object
                item = {
                    src: el.getAttribute('href'),
                    w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                    h: parseInt(size[1], 10),
                    author: el.getAttribute('data-author')
                };

                item.el = el; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn

                if(childElements.length > 0) {
                  item.msrc = childElements[0].getAttribute('src'); // thumbnail url
                  if(childElements.length > 1) {
                      item.title = childElements[1].innerHTML; // caption (contents of figure)
                  }
                }


                var mediumSrc = el.getAttribute('data-med');
                if(mediumSrc) {
                    size = el.getAttribute('data-med-size').split('x');
                    // "medium-sized" image
                    item.m = {
                        src: mediumSrc,
                        w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                        h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
                    };
                }
                // original image
                item.o = {
                    src: item.src,
                    w: item.w,
                    h: item.h
                };

                items.push(item);
            }

            return items;
        };

        // find nearest parent element
        var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
            return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
        };

        var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

            var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

            var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
                return el.tagName === 'A';
            });

            if(!clickedListItem) {
                return;
            }

            var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode;

            var childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
                numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
                nodeIndex = 0,
                index;

            for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
                if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                    continue; 
                }

                if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                    index = nodeIndex;
                    break;
                }
                nodeIndex++;
            }

            if(index >= 0) {
                openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
            }
            return false;
        };

        var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
            var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
            params = {};

            if(hash.length < 5) { // pid=1
                return params;
            }

            var vars = hash.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                if(!vars[i]) {
                    continue;
                }
                var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
                if(pair.length < 2) {
                    continue;
                }           
                params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }

            if(params.gid) {
                params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
            }

            return params;
        };

        var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
            var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
                gallery,
                options,
                items;

            items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

            // define options (if needed)
            options = {

                galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

                getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                    // See Options->getThumbBoundsFn section of docs for more info
                    var thumbnail = items[index].el.children[0],
                        pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                        rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                    return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
                },

                addCaptionHTMLFn: function(item, captionEl, isFake) {
                    if(!item.title) {
                        captionEl.children[0].innerText = '';
                        return false;
                    }
                    captionEl.children[0].innerHTML = item.title +  '<br/><small>Photo: ' + item.author + '</small>';
                    return true;
                },

            };


            if(fromURL) {
                if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                    // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                    // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                        if(items[j].pid == index) {
                            options.index = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
                }
            } else {
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
            }

            // exit if index not found
            if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
                return;
            }



            var radios = document.getElementsByName('gallery-style');
            for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
                if (radios[i].checked) {
                    if(radios[i].id == 'radio-all-controls') {

                    } else if(radios[i].id == 'radio-minimal-black') {
                        options.mainClass = 'pswp--minimal--dark';
                        options.barsSize = {top:0,bottom:0};
                        options.captionEl = false;
                        options.fullscreenEl = false;
                        options.shareEl = false;
                        options.bgOpacity = 0.85;
                        options.tapToClose = true;
                        options.tapToToggleControls = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(disableAnimation) {
                options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
            }

            // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
            gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);

            // see: http://photoswipe.com/documentation/responsive-images.html
            var realViewportWidth,
                useLargeImages = false,
                firstResize = true,
                imageSrcWillChange;

            gallery.listen('beforeResize', function() {

                var dpiRatio = window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;
                dpiRatio = Math.min(dpiRatio, 2.5);
                realViewportWidth = gallery.viewportSize.x * dpiRatio;


                if(realViewportWidth >= 1200 || (!gallery.likelyTouchDevice && realViewportWidth > 800) || screen.width > 1200 ) {
                    if(!useLargeImages) {
                        useLargeImages = true;
                        imageSrcWillChange = true;
                    }

                } else {
                    if(useLargeImages) {
                        useLargeImages = false;
                        imageSrcWillChange = true;
                    }
                }

                if(imageSrcWillChange && !firstResize) {
                    gallery.invalidateCurrItems();
                }

                if(firstResize) {
                    firstResize = false;
                }

                imageSrcWillChange = false;

            });

            gallery.listen('gettingData', function(index, item) {
                if( useLargeImages ) {
                    item.src = item.o.src;
                    item.w = item.o.w;
                    item.h = item.o.h;
                } else {
                    item.src = item.m.src;
                    item.w = item.m.w;
                    item.h = item.m.h;
                }
            });

            gallery.init();
        };

        // select all gallery elements
        var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );
        for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
            galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
            galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
        }

        // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
        var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
        if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
            openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
        }
    };

    initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.grid-item');

})();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED
Removed the

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <a href="fashion/01.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="fashion/600/01.jpg" data-med-size="600x800" data-author="">
      <img src="fashion/600/01.jpg" alt="" class="over" /><div class="overlay"><img class="zoom" src="images/mag.png" alt="mag" width="37" height="39"></div>
    </a>
    </div>
```

and replaced with:

```
    <a class="grid-item" href="fashion/01.jpg" data-size="900x1200" data-med="fashion/600/01.jpg" data-med-size="600x800" data-author="">
      <img src="fashion/600/01.jpg" alt="" class="over" /><div class="overlay"><img class="zoom" src="images/mag.png" alt="mag" width="37" height="39"></div>
    </a>
```